# Is there any documentation bundle for symfony?

Tags: symfony

Is there any documentation bundle for Symfony? Where simple help pages can be created / edited? Or separate software that can be integrated but not in iframe?

Answer (score 0):

For real good documentations Sphinx is much better. You can generate different formats from your sources it's very cool.

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/

The only bundle for SF i know is the APIDocBundle but that is more for Api documentations.

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html

Comment: For separate use I would prefer Confluence but would like something integrated